# C++ equivalent of Python's array access with comparison (array[condition] = value)

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm following this OpenCV Watershed tutorial, but porting it to C++: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

Simply put, at some points in the tutorial the author will access and assign pixels in the matrix using an operation similar to this:

```py
markers[unknown==255] = 0
```

or this

```py
img[markers == -1] = [255,0,0]
```

What I want to do is the equivalent of said operation, but in C++. It *feels* simple, but I just can't get my head around how to do it elegantly.

For the first case, I could work around it using `cv::findNonZero`, but for the second it becomes slightly more complicated and I'd like to avoid hacky solutions.

Honestly, this has probably been answered already but I have no idea which terms would bring this up on a search, any pointer or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d8/da9/watershed_8cpp-example.html)?

Comment: I did not. However that one requires manually marking the areas which you want to be segmented, even if roughly. I'll see if I can adapt it to be automatic. Also, it appears they perform simple access, with two for loops. I hope that's not the only way.

Comment: There is no equivalent for Python syntax in C++. You can check out [`std::replace_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace), but I don't know if OpenCV works well with standard library algorithms.

Comment: Alrighty. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenCV's [`inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) method with lower = upper boundary to obtain a mask representing the desired pixels to be changed, and then use this mask in OpenCV's [`setTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a0440e2a164c0b0d8462fb1e487be9876) method:

```cpp
// Read image
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("image.png");

// Mask everything, that's pure blue (#0000FF)
cv::Mat mask;
cv::inRange(img, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), mask);

// Write mask
cv::imwrite("mask.png", mask);

// Update value in mask to red
img.setTo(cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), mask);
cv::imwrite("image_new.png", img);

return 0;
```

This is some input image:

[image: Input]

This the obtained mask:

[image: Mask]

And this is the updated image:

[image: New image]

Hope that helps!